How can I be able to make groups in my classes?
One of the teachers in my building showed me where she could make groups when assigning classwork to students. There is not that option on mine. I have tried going to the "People" tab and the "Classwork" tab. Neither of them have it anywhere. I have even tried updating everything. How can I get this?
I tried looking everywhere including in settings.

This is probably not a great question for StackOverflow (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), but I see you are new to the site.
If you search something like "make student groups in google classroom" in Google search, you'll see the announcement post which explains the license requirements and that the feature has not yet rolled out to all users.
Hope that helps
